# How to automatically change texts on a dynamic webpage using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to run functions to change texts in multiple tables on a webpage. The tables are populated dynamically when user does multiple clicks or searches on the page. So, loading these functions on page load doesn't serve any good.

My question is how can I monitor these AJAX call and load functions as a callback whenever a DOM Node is changed or an attribute is added?

Any thoughts? I have a starting trouble.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has built-in callback functions for their shorthand ajax functions like `get()` and `load()`, and you can set success and error callbacks though the parameters in the `ajax()` method.

Please refer to jQuery's robust documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks Neil. I went thru' it-but little confused with how to implement on the current page without attaching anything to any click events. Basically, if table changes, I want my scripts to make changes on the "changed table". I tried something like this:
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
 $('#myTableContent').load(pathname, function() {
 alert('Load was performed.');
});

But I am missing something!!!

Comment: are you using ready wrappers around your jQuery code? You need to make sure the DOM is ready before trying to manipulate it. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Do you have a sample code for listener which listens to all ajax requests whenever it's made?

Comment: jQuery 1.8 and later have introduced the `ajaxComplete()` method : http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/